# Show contact name in notification with react native

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

We are trying to build kind of a chat app in react native + expo. We want to create a notification with the message sender's name (as saved on the receiver's phone contacts).
We thought about sending a quiet notification, with the sender's phone number in the "data", and on the client-side, when receiving this quiet notification, create a "local" notification with the name of contact linked to this phone number.
We already have a context with all the contacts on the phone, but as the backgroundNotificationHandler most be defined outside of the React element, we have no access to our context.
Is our approach right? If so - how can we obtain information from the contacts context? If not - how would you approach this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Humm, Why don't you think about sending Phone Contact Name to the backend before pushing notification from backend with the name.

Comment: the problem is that we want the name of the contact saved in the phone that got the notification, not the name in the phone that sent the notification